# Run Frequencies Using Grouped Variable in SPSS

Tags: frequency, spss

I think I have a pretty easy question that I can't find the answer to.  I have divided my data into two different groups designated as 1 or 2.  If I would like to run a frequency for another variable on just the 1, how do I do that?

For example, all my 1's are people from the United States, and 2's are international.  Another variable is what age group they are in.  How do I see the ages for just those who are 1's?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to run the frequencies for one particular group, you can use a `TEMPORARY.` and then a `SELECT IF` command. Something like this.

```
TEMPORARY.
SELECT IF Group = 1.
FREQ VAR = MyVar.
```

This is convenient for one group, but for multiple groups I would suggest you examine the `SPLIT FILE` command, which will generate subsets of tables for each distinct group. Something like:

```
SORT CASES BY AgeGroup.
SPLIT FILE BY AgeGroup.
FREQ VAR = MyVar.
SPLIT FILE OFF.
```

This will generate a set of frequency tables for `MyVar` for each of the distinct groups in the `AgeGroup` variables.